# How does QGraphicsView receive mouse move events?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

Briefly I want to track mouse coordinate over a `QGraphicsView`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789535/2918210) works well for a `QLabel` object, but not works as expected when I switch to `QGraphicsView` as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)

        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.installEventFilter(self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)


    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
            source is self.graphicsView):
            pos = event.pos()
            print('mouse move: (%d, %d)' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.resize(200, 100)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Specifically, it seems like that the event is caught only when my cursor moves **accross the border** of the QGraphicsView (the black lines).

[image]

Could anyone tell me why and is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For certain widgets, you need to use its viewport instead:

```
    self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
    ...

def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
        source is self.graphicsView.viewport()):
    ...
```

Comment: Probably for all that are a `QAbstractScrollArea`. What about overriding `viewportEvent()`? Would be another possibility. (I never really used event filters so far because usually I can override the right event anyway but I wonder what is better.)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to override `mouseMoveEvent(event)` of `QGraphicsView` directly.

Example:

```
from PySide import QtGui

class MyGraphicsView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('mouseMoveEvent: pos {}'.format(event.pos()))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.graphicsView = MyGraphicsView(self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
window.resize(200, 100)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative :)